# WooCommerce 3.3: Override default image-size "shop_thumbnail"

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Since the 3.3 update of WC I've run in to some trouble with thumbnails.
Thumbnails show correctly on subcategory- and productpages, but show a 100x100 image on the main shop page.

In the source the class "shop_thumbnail" is used, and this is a default image-size that comes with WooCommerce. Is it possible to override this image-size?

I've already tried to add the following to my functions.php:

```
add_image_size ( 'shop_thumbnail', 600, 450, array('center', 'center') );
```

Thanks!

Comment: you need to hook in on "after_setup_theme" and add it as a function.

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/178235/child-theme-overriding-add-image-size-by-a-child-theme